why is difficult in camel use sftp process [1:StreamDownload all .xml on sftp ; 2:extract xml element value for each file] with PoolEnrich ? not From
i try simply in stream the content of each xml file on ftp.
i have try many code from web....
the last is :
 .loopDoWhile(simple("${body} != null &&
 ${exchangeProperty.tmp_finished} == false"))   
 .pollEnrich().simple("sftp:{{xxxx.sftp.host}}" + ?noop=true" +
                     "&includeExt=xml" +
                     "&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true" +
                     "&idempotent=true" +
                     "&useList=true" +
                     "&download=true" +
                     "&streamDownload=true" +
                     "&disconnect=true" +
                     "&autoCreate=false" +
                     "&userName={{xxxx.sftp.userName}}" +
                     "&password={{xxxx.sftp.password}}").timeout(1500)
                      .process(exchange -> {
                          final Throwable ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Throwable.class);
                          if (ex!=null && ex.getMessage().contains("GenericFileOperationFailedException"))
                           {
                            log.info("ex.getMessage(): " + exchange.getMessage().getBody());
                            exchange.getMessage().setHeader("tmp_finished", "true");
                           } else if (exchange.getMessage().getBody() != null) {
                              log.info(".getBody() != null: " + exchange.getMessage().getBody());
                              log.info("headers : " + exchange.getMessage().getHeaders());
                              batchSize = batchSize+1;
                              log.info("batchSize : " + batchSize);
                              String elementName2Value= XPathBuilder.xpath("//*[local-name()='elementName']/*[local-name()='elementName2']/text()").evaluate(exchange,String.class);
                              map_of_files.put(exchange.getMessage().getHeader("CamelFileNameOnly",
 String.class),elementName2Value);
                              exchange.setProperty("tmp_finished", "false");
                            }
                        })
    .end()// end pollEnrich
.end() // end loopDoWhile

map_of_files  is just a hashmap with filename  and  elementName2Value
but only 1 file... :(  in my ftp have 2 files .xml
why ?
Thanks.

Why don't use just  a simple sftp endpoint, which will automatically poll and consume every file put in the directory mentioned ? Why necessarily use loopDoWhile and pollEnrich ? pollEnrich is designed to poll just one file.
